# Why is POST array empty in 404 or other custom IIS error page?

Tags: php, iis, error-handling, iis-7.5

I've set up a custom php 404 error page, by `IIS > MySite > Error Pages` but the **$_POST** array is always empty. Is this normal? How do I tell IIS to pass POST data to PHP error page?

*IIS 7.5*

Comment: Why should a Request, that was never valid (That's why you sending 404), contain information for further processing? What do you want to process?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at `web.config` and the `Rewriting Module`, if I guess your intend right :)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt In the normal circumstacnes there is no need to process the POST data, but capturing it may provide more insight in debugging. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: This Answer is given in reading between the lines.

---

As I stated in the comments, there is no reason to process some user input, if the request is invalid. *HTTP Status Code 404* literaly means, this Request is invalid, because the resource can not be found.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> The requested resource could not be found but may be available again
>   in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

What is a Post? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)

> Per RFC 7231, the POST method should be used for any context in which
>   a request is non-idempotent: that is, **it causes a change in server
>   state each time it is performed**, such as submitting a comment to a
>   blog post or voting in an online poll.[...]

I can not confirm or deny, if it is true, that `IIS` don't have Post's on `404`, since I never tried this. But it would make no sense to support.

---

For me It sounds like, you want to rewrite some Request. For this you need the [Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could have a `web.config` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RequestString">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?requestString={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

On your `index.php` you can have:

```
echo $_GET['requestString'];
```

If you call the url `http://yourwebsite.com/foo/bar` you will echo in the `index.php` the string `foo/bar`.

Now you can split the string, make some decisions with it, and perform different actions on different values.

Comment: Perfect! I've tried rewrite module but didn't trust it because the rules were based purely on the request strings. So not as accurate because IIS did not perform the actual file existance check, like custom error pages functionality did. **IsFile + IsDirectory** conditions make all the difference. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Though, I've changed the RegEx to `^(.+)$`. Not that it makes much difference, because `/` will probably be picked up by the IsDirectory condition, but feels right.